# Loop through all cells and delete any zero cell (shift up)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, loops, vba

This seems like it should be a fairly simple task but I can't seem to get it to work- I just want a simple macro that will loop through all the cells in my worksheet. If the cell is equal to zero (or blank for kicks), then just delete it, moving the other cells in the column up one.

I got nowhere trying to do it on the whole document, so I tried to do it on a single column :

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
For i = 81 To 1 Step -1
If Range("A" & i) = "0" Then Range("A" & i).Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

I don't want to delete any rows, just the individual cells if they have value `0`.

But evidently still getting nowhere.

Comment: i'm very interested if you can do that in a few clicks !

Answer (score 3):

Select the range to delete blanks within. Home > Editing – Find & Select, Go To Special, Blanks, OK, select within array, Delete…, Shift cells up, OK.

To apply the same process to cells containing `0` select range to delete `0`s within and start (ie before above) by replacing these with nothing:

Home > Editing, Find & Select, enter `0` in Find what:, check Match entire cell contents and ensure Replace with: is empty, Replace All.

Comment: the cells i want to delete are not blanks but have value 0

Comment: @pnuts, when you say select within array, Delete, do you mean right-click on one of the selected cells? For the Delete, would that be the delete key or the Delete button on the Cells section of the Home tab of the ribbon?

Comment: ok got it - ctrl+h, enter 0, leave replace blank, check 'match all cell contents' and voila

Comment: @chuff once they're highlighted you click delete in the toolbar above, move cells up, and it's done

Comment: + 1. Non VBA over VBA? Any Day! :P

Comment: :P I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

This small macro will delete both blanks and zeros:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rKill As Range, r As Range
    Set rKill = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value = 0 Or r.Value = "" Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(rKill, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If rKill Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rKill.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

As **pnuts** pointed out, this can be a little slow.  The following might be a little quicker:

```
Sub dural2()
    With Cells
        .Replace "0", ""
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
End Sub
```